# How to define the constructor in a child class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am having difficulty trying to implement a constructor for my child class. I understand the purpose of the constructor is to set the states of the class to the values passed? am I correct in this?

I am getting an error;

*no matching function for call to 'superclass'*

My question is do I have to link my constructor for a child class to the superclass? what is the relationship in terms of constructors between the two classes?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Buildings
{

private:

    float price, area;
    string city;


public:

    Buildings(float, float, string);
   // Buildings(float, float, float);
    void virtual display();
    void virtual getprice(float);
    void virtual getcity(string);
    void virtual getarea(float);

};

Buildings::Buildings(float b_price, float b_area, string b_city):price(b_price), area(b_area), city(b_city)
{

}

void Buildings::display()
{

    cout<<"The city, price and area(sqft) of the building are: "<<city<<endl<<price<<endl<<area;
}

void Buildings::getprice(float aprice)
{

    price = aprice;//potential error handling

}

void Buildings::getarea(float asize)
{
    area = asize;
}

void Buildings::getcity(string acity)
{
    city  = acity;
}



class Apartment:public Buildings
{


private:
    float numtennants;
    float rent;
    float rentpr;

public:

    Apartment(float numres, float numrent, float numrentpr);
    void virtual display();
    void virtual avgrent(float);
    void virtual totrent(float);
    void virtual totres(float);

};

Apartment::Apartment(float numres, float numrent, float numrentpr):numtennants(numres),rent(numrent),rentpr(numrentpr)
{}

void Apartment::display()
{
    Buildings::display();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Buildings` doesn't have a default constructor. You must explicitly call the only `Buildings` constructor that exists, passing along the suitable arguments.

If you want do disallow public default-construction of `Buildings` objects, but allow child-classes to use it, you can make a default constructor that is `protected`. Like

```
class Buildings
{
public:
    // Public constructor, only way to construct object of this class
    // for the general public
    Buildings(float, float, string);

    // Other public functions...

protected:
    // Default constructor, which initializes the private members
    // to some suitable values
    // Only usable by child-classes
    Buildings()
        : price(0), area(0), city("")
    {}

private:
    float price, area;
    string city;
};
```

Comment: ah I see thanks, so if I do this and use a default constructor for my buildings class, do I still need to implement my constructor for that buildings class in the public?

Comment: is my constructor for the child class the same as in my code then? sorry just trying to get my head around it

Comment: @TonyHibbert You should not need to modify the `Apartment` class with the example in my answer. But be noted that the `Buildings` member variables will have the default values initialized by the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the parent class's constructor in your child class's [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
struct A {
  A(int a) : a_(a) {}
  int a_;
};

struct B : public A {
  B(int a, int b) : A(a), b_(b) {}
  int b_;
};
```

Comment: so it would look like; Apartment::Apartment(float numres, float numrent, float numrentpr):Buildings(float, float, string);

Comment: sorry it would be this no; Apartment::Apartment(float numres, float numrent, float numrentpr):price(b_price), area(b_area), city(b_city);